# ld error while compiling caffe: libpng and libgfortran not found, shared libraries

Tags: ubuntu, g++, shared-libraries, ld, caffe

I'm trying to compile caffe on ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Anaconda, in CPU-only mode and with OpenBLAS. Unfortunately, I get an ld error.

I followed the instructions, added the dependencies that didn't come with Anaconda and adjusted the Makefile.config accordingly, especially included the Anaconda path.
When I do `make all` I get the error you see below (I also included the Makefile.config), even though the two files that were not found are in the anaconda/lib folder and in their respective pkgs folders as shared libraries.

Thank you very much for your help!

Terminal:

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpng15.so.15, needed by /home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libgfortran.so.1, needed by /home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopenblas.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_alpha@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_pow_i4_i4'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_palette_to_rgb@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_swap@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_write_end@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_write_image@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_write_info@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_update_info@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_strategy@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_info@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_image@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_compare_string'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_bgr@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_init_io@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_packing@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_pow_r8_i4'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_pow_r4_i4'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_etime'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_error@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopenblas.so: undefined reference to `_gfortran_copy_string'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_read_end@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_rgb_to_gray@PNG15_0'
/home/mclab/anaconda/lib/libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `png_set_filter@PNG15_0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin] Error 1
```

Makefile.config:

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
# USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
 CPU_ONLY := 1

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
 CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := open
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
 BLAS_INCLUDE := /home/mclab/anaconda/pkgs/openblas-0.2.14-1/include
 BLAS_LIB := /home/mclab/anaconda/pkgs/openblas-0.2.14-1/lib

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /home/mclab/anaconda/include/python2.7 \
        /home/mclab/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ORIGINAL:
 ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda
 PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
         $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
         $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \
# MODIFIED
# ANACONDA_HOME := /home/mclab/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /home/mclab/anaconda/include \
#        /home/mclab/anaconda/include/python2.7 \
#        /home/mclab/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
# PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
 PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
 WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
# DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like i was able to solve this by myself. I don't know whether it's a good solution though, so I appreciate any comment: In the folder /etc/ld.so.conf.d I created a file fooLibrary.conf. This file contains only the full path to Anaconda's lib-folder. After `sudo ldconfig`, ld was able to find the relevant packages. Once I was done I deleted the file again, but I doubt the problem is solved conclusively. Hence I'll be glad about comments or better solutions.